# Recursion results in unwanted looping

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I am having some difficulty using recursion.  Below, I have a block of code that is attempting to solve a puzzle.  `process()` generates permutations, then `solve()` runs through those permutations and checks each one.  If a solution fails at a certain position, the function then removes all possible solutions that begin the same way, and re-runs itself recursively.  The `test_it()` function is called in `solve()` as a means of determining when a solution is incorrect.

This gives the correct result in the end, but when I added the print line:

```
print 'Fail', combo, count
```

I noticed it the function seems to recognize the correct solution, but then continues iterating anyway.  I think I may be messing something up with the nested loops because once it reaches the line:

```
return combo
```

it doesn't terminate.

```
import itertools

final_side = [{(1,2): [[1,0,1,1]]},\
              {(2,1): [[1,1,0,1]]},\
              {1: [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]},\
              {1: [[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,1]]}]

final_top = [{2: [[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1]]},\
              {(1,1): [[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1]]},\
              {(1,1): [[1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,1],[0,1,0,1]]},\
              {2: [[1,1,0,0],[0,1,1,0],[0,0,1,1]]}]

def process():
    # Generates all permutations
    possible = []
    possibilities = []
    a = []

    for dic in final_side:
        for values in dic.values():
            possible.append(len(values))            

    for number in possible:
        a.append([x for x in range(number)])

    b = map(list, itertools.product(*a))

    return b

def test_it(listx, final_top, final_side):

    length = len(listx)
    place = []    

    if length > 0:
        pot = map(list, zip(*listx))
        for j in range(len(pot)):
            x = final_top[j].values()[0]
            test = [x[i][:length] for i in range(len(x))]

            if pot[j] not in test:
                return False

            else:
                loc = [x for x,val in enumerate(test) if val== pot[j]]
                place.append(loc)
    return place


def solve(listx):

    solution = []     

    for combo in listx[:]:
        pos = -1
        temp = []
        count = 0
        for num in combo:
            pos += 1
            temp.append(final_side[pos].values()[0][num])
            place = test_it(temp, final_top, final_side)    

            if place == False:
                blah = combo[:pos+1]
                listx = [x for x in listx if not x[:pos+1] == combo[:pos+1]]
                print 'Fail', combo, count                 
                solve(listx)

            else:
                count += 1
                if count == 4:
                    return combo

def main():


    a = process()
    solution = solve(a)

    print solution

main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring the return value of *recursive* calls:

```
if place == False:
    blah = combo[:pos+1]
    listx = [x for x in listx if not x[:pos+1] == combo[:pos+1]]
    print 'Fail', combo, count                 
    solve(listx)
```

The return value of the `solve()` call there is dropped; it won't be passed to the next caller, nor are you ending the loop there.

Add a `return` to exit that level of your recursive calls:

```
if not place:
    blah = combo[:pos+1]
    listx = [x for x in listx if not x[:pos+1] == combo[:pos+1]]
    print 'Fail', combo, count                 
    return solve(listx)
```

I also replaced `place == False` with `not place`, a much better way to test for boolean false.

With these changes your script outputs:

```
$ bin/python test.py 
Fail [0, 0, 0, 0] 2
Fail [0, 0, 1, 0] 2
Fail [0, 0, 2, 0] 3
[0, 0, 2, 1]
```

Comment: That fixes it!  I guess I should've read up a bit more on the differences between recursion and normal looping.